# Java assignment :Forloop wont fall back into my while loop and is giving a null pointer error

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, null-pointer

In this snippet for my assignment i have two arrays of type member and account. They are tied together by ssn that is given by both in member and member account creation.  My problem is that after the arrays are searched through i get an error like:
ive created a member with ssn 1111 name: John Doe state:UT Account:123 balance:1000

```
 AccountNumber: 123Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Banker.main(Banker.java:116)
```

What i need it to do is print the information below and fall back into my menu while  loop awaiting input.

```
//make a deposit
else if(iMenu==2)
{
    myScan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Account Number:");
    accountnumber=myScan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter SSN:");
    ssn=myScan.nextInt();

    for(int x=0;x<memberAcc.length;x++)
    {
        if(memberAcc[x].getAccountNumber()==accountnumber && memberAcc[x].getSSN()==ssn  )
        {
            System.out.println("Enter Deposit Ammount: ");
            deposit=myScan.nextDouble();
            memberAcc[x].MakeDeposit(deposit);
            System.out.print("\nYour Balance is: " + memberAcc[x].getAccountBalance() + "\nAccountNumber: " + memberAcc[x].getAccountNumber());
        }
    }
    for(int y=0;y<newMember.length;y++)
    {
        if( ssn==newMember[y].getSSN())
        {
            System.out.print("\nFirstName:"+newMember[y].getFirstName()+"\nLast Name: "+newMember[y].getLastName());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error no Match!");// help
        }
    }//end for loop
}// end deposit
```

Comment: Would be nice to know which is line 116 in the snippet, because the exception is coming from that line.

Comment: Paste executable code so we know what's going on.

Comment: Line 116 is System.out.println("Enter Deposit Ammount: ");

Comment: `memberAcc[x]` is probably null.

Comment: i doubt your NPE is coming from system.out.println.

Comment: i doubt it too thats whats odd.

Comment: also i checked if memberAcc[x] was null and its not

Comment: @jlewis.is Have you tried using debugger?

Comment: yes and it creates the instances just fine but still throws the error. im still working on it. and i have researched this you guys but im still having problems

Answer (score 0):

alright so this is what worked, the null characters in the array were causing issues and were returning the last null in the array so i forced the array to break after each if/else statement by putting x = memberAcc.length +1; and y = newMember.length +1; to do this. Causing the entire array to be checked and then forced to be broken allowing me to return to my Menu while loop.